# How to call a function that returns a promise from a different file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm stuck with promises in my React project. I would like all functions that communicate with the firebase to be in a separate file/files, but I can't figure out how to call them from a component file.

This is an extract from the file with database functions (DatabaseFunctions.js):

```js
import firebase from '../.Database/firebase';

const db = firebase.firestore();

export const getAllUsers = () => {
  let results = [];
  db.collection("users").get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        results.push(doc.id);
      });
    })
    .then(() => {
      return results;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      throw error;
    })
}
```

And this is how I try to call it from the component, but it returns 'undefined':

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Paper } from '@material-ui/core';
import * as dbFunctions from './DatabaseFunctions';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [output, setOutput] = useState('');

  const handleGetAllUsers = () => {
    const allUsers = dbFunctions.getAllUsers()
    setOutput(JSON.stringify(allUsers, null, "\t"));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Paper>
        <button onClick={() => handleGetAllUsers()}>getAllUsers</button>
      </Paper>
      <Paper>
        <pre>{output}</pre>
      </Paper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

another way that I've tried:

```js
const handleGetAllUsers = () => {
  const allUsers = dbFunctions.getAllUsers()
    .then(res => {
      return res;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return err;
    })

  setOutput(JSON.stringify(allUsers, null, "\t"));
}
```

but this one gives an error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

The only way I manage to get it to work is by putting this function directly in the component:

```js
const handleGetAllUsers = () => {
  let results = [];
  db.collection("users").get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        results.push(doc.id);
      });
    })
    .then(() => {
      setOutput(JSON.stringify(results, null, "\t"));
    })
    .catch(error => {
      setOutput(JSON.stringify(error, null, "\t"));
    })
}
```

but that would mean that I don't follow DRY (the same function would be repeated in many files) and the code is much harder to maintain.

I would really appreciate some advice!
Thanks

Comment: You are not returning anything inside `getAllUsers`, you should `return results` at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing with promises is that the code runs asynchronously, so you need to return the promise from your firebase code, and then in the calling function, you need to use `.then()` to access the data.

In DatabaseFunctions.js

```
import firebase from '../.Database/firebase';

const db = firebase.firestore();

export const getAllUsers = () => {
  let results = [];
  **return** db.collection("users").get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        results.push(doc.id);
      });
    })
    .then(() => {
      return results;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      throw error;
    })
}
```

and

```
const handleGetAllUsers = () => {
    dbFunctions.getAllUsers().then(allUsers => 
    setOutput(JSON.stringify(allUsers, null, "\t")));
}
```